# How to do fields names uppercase in JAXB in java object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb

I am trying to convert a Java Object to XML using JAXB and it works for me, but it converts the name of the class fields with a lowercase letter and I don’t know how to change to capital letters.
For example, my class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "StockQuoteRequest")
@Component
public class StockQuoteRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "Security")
    private Security securities;

// constructor   
// getter/setter
// toString
}
```

Here is the **Security** class:

```
@Component
public class Security {

    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;

    // constructor   
    // getter/setter
    // toString
}
```

For the **StockQuoteRequest** class, the Security field is capitalized, but for the Security class, its fields (*name, lastName, address*) are printed with a small one.

I tried to add an annotation in the Security class above each field

```
@XmlElement(name = "Name")
@XmlElement(name = "LastName")
@XmlElement(name = "Address")
```

But this does not work at all.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the class `Security` be also annotated with `@XmlRootElement`?

Comment: @dan1st No, because it is a sub-element, not a root element, and the sub-element name is defined by the `securities` field, not by the `Security` class.

Comment: If `Security` has fields like `name` and `lastName`, then it make no sense at all for it to be a *singleton* Spring component, i.e. that `@Component` annotation makes no sense. --- Neither does the `@Component` annotation on `StockQuoteRequest`.

Comment: Adding the `@XmlElement(name = "Name")` on the `name` field should have worked. How about you show us the actual code you say doesn't work. and maybe show us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the following exception in Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_181) when trying your code, i.e. when I added standard getter/setter methods:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Class has two properties of the same name "securities"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public Security StockQuoteRequest.getSecurities()
        at StockQuoteRequest
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private Security StockQuoteRequest.securities
        at StockQuoteRequest
```

To fix, I had to do *one* of 3 things:

- Move the `@XmlElement(name = "Security")` annotation down to the `getSecurities()` method
- Add `@XmlTransient` to the `getSecurities()` method
- Add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` (or `FIELD`) to the `StockQuoteRequest` class

When I did any of those, I would get output like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StockQuoteRequest>
    <Security>
        <address>North Pole</address>
        <lastName>Doe</lastName>
        <name>John</name>
    </Security>
</StockQuoteRequest>
```

Notice how the 3 sub-elements are in the wrong order. To fix, add `@XmlType(propOrder = { "name", "lastName", "address" })` to the `Security` class.

When I then added the 3 `@XmlElement` annotations, showed in the question, to the `Security` class, and applied similar fix to prevent exception, I get what I expected:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<StockQuoteRequest>
    <Security>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
        <Address>North Pole</Address>
    </Security>
</StockQuoteRequest>
```

Full [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get the above output:

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StockQuoteRequest request = new StockQuoteRequest(
                new Security("John", "Doe", "North Pole"));

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(StockQuoteRequest.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(request, System.out);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "StockQuoteRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class StockQuoteRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "Security")
    private Security securities;

    public StockQuoteRequest() {
    }

    public StockQuoteRequest(Security securities) {
        this.securities = securities;
    }

    public Security getSecurities() {
        return this.securities;
    }

    public void setSecurities(Security securities) {
        this.securities = securities;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StockQuoteRequest" + this.securities;
    }

}

@XmlType(propOrder = { "name", "lastName", "address" })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class Security {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @XmlElement(name = "Address")
    private String address;

    public Security() {
    }

    public Security(String name, String lastName, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Security[name=" + this.name + ", lastName=" + this.lastName + ", address=" + this.address + "]";
    }
}
```